# Manually trigger flash message with jQuery .click function in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple link that I need to display a flash message but not sure where to begin.  All my searches revealed long jQuery & Ajax methods, but nothing that is as simple and similar as using a jQuery `.click` function.

What I'm trying to do, which I know doesn't work:

**Link**

```
<%= link_to 'Pre-paid with Check', root_path, class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'prepaid' %>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#prepaid').click(function(){
    notice('Thank you, your order has been received.');
});
```

Comment: Is this link supposed to do something? Or literally just add a message to the page?

Comment: @jvillian It actually sits right next to a purchase button that takes the amount from the form and passes it to Stripe and charges the card.  Since this association is selling Memorial Plaques, some donors send a check in, but we still need the plaque information, so instead of having to make a payment, this is simply a dummy button that takes them away from the page and displays a message, thus giving them some verification that the info was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, it seems like you could do something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Pre-paid with Check', root_path(message: "Thank you, your order has been received."), class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'prepaid' %>
```

Then in your controller action (the one that maps to `root_path`), you could grab that `message` param and do whatever you like with it (assign it to flash, pass it to a partial, assign it to variable that is accessed in your `html.erb`, etc.).